# ConfigServer firewall enable SSH for dynamic dns

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall

I am running ConfigServer Firewall on my server.  Currently I have a few dynamic dns entries added to the `LFD Dynamic DNS` section.  Those dyn dns hosts though cannot SSH to the server - I can only get those hosts SSH access if I added their (ever changing) IPs to the `Firewall Allow IPs` section. But that pretty much defeats the purpose of dyn dns if I am having to constantly add their changing IPs to a permit list.

The permitted dynIP hosts though can access the server WHM/cPanel via web gui; they just can't SSH.

To get around this, in the `Firewall Allow IPs` section I am forced to add the entire /24 their new IPs are coming from because I have found that if the user renews their IP they are typically coming from the same IP segment, which helps reduce the amount of dynIP entries I have to add to the permit list - but I am seeing it changing to all new subnets more often these days.

```
tcp|in|d=522|s=192.200.103.0/24 # SSH port for John Smith's dynIP (01/01/23)
```

What and where do I need to add their dyn dns entries so they can also SSH?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom allow rule for SSH traffic that uses the dynamic DNS hostnames instead of IP addresses. You can add this rule to the "csf.allow" file on your server.

```
tcp|in|d=22|s=/path/to/dynamic-dns-hostnames.txt
```

Inside the "dynamic-dns-hostnames.txt" file, you can add one hostname per line, like this:

```
hostname1.example.com
hostname2.example.com
```

Make sure to use the actual hostnames that you're using for dynamic DNS. You can add or remove hostnames from this file as needed, and you won't need to update the firewall rule itself.

Comment: Wow...thanks Salim!  I had no idea the `s=` could be a path to a file.  Could the `dynamic-dns-hostnames.txt` file simply point to CSF's own `csf.dyndns` file....or does it need to be its own unique file?

Comment: In your case, it is possible to use the csf.dyndns file directly in your custom rule by using the file: prefix. e.g: tcp|in|d=22|s=file:/etc/csf/csf.dyndns

Comment: Great to know.  I decided to use a custom file though - because then that gives me the ability to have two different types of user access: WHM/GUI access and separately SSH access.  99% of the time they would be the same, but I can see future scenarios where I might need to permit one versus the other.  Thanks again.